# aws lambda s3 events for existing files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am considering moving to lambdas and after spending some time reading docs and various blogs with user experiences I am still struggling with a simple question. Is there a proposed/proper way to use lambda with existing s3 files?

I have an s3 bucket that contains archived data spanning a couple of years. The size of these data is rather large (hundreds of GB). Each file is a simple txt file. Each line in the file represents an event and it's just a comma separated string.

My endgame is to consume these files, parse each one of them line by line apply some transformation, create batches of lines and send them to an external service. From what I've read so far, if I write a proper lambda, this will be triggered by an s3 event (for example an upload of a new file).

Is there a way to apply the lambda to all the existing contents of my bucket?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem I solved it with minimal changes to my existing Lambda function. The solution involves creating API Gateway trigger (in addition to S3 trigger) - the API gateway trigger is used to process historical files in S3 & the regular S3 trigger will processes my files as new files are uploaded to my S3 bucket.

Initially - I started by building my function to expect a S3 event as trigger. Recall that the S3 events have this [structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) - so I would look for the S3 bucket name and key to process - like so:

```
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')

        temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        video_filename = os.path.basename(key)
        local_video_filename = os.path.join(temp_dir.name, video_filename)
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, local_video_filename)
```

But when you send the API Gateway trigger there is no "Records" object in the request/event. You can use query parameters in the API Gateway Trigger - so the modification required to the above snippet of code is:

```
    if 'Records' in event:
        # this means we are working off of an S3 event
        records_to_process = event['Records']
    else:
        # this is for ad-hoc posts via API Gateway trigger for Lambda
        records_to_process = [{
        "s3":{"bucket": {"name":  event["queryStringParameters"]["bucket"]},
              "object":{"key": event["queryStringParameters"]["file"]}}
    }]

    for record in records_to_process:
        # below lines of code s same as the earlier snippet of code
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')

        temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        video_filename = os.path.basename(key)
        local_video_filename = os.path.join(temp_dir.name, video_filename)
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, local_video_filename)
```

[Postman result of sending the post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVcze.png)

Answer (score 1):

For existing resources you would need to write a script that gets a listing of all your resources and sends each item to a Lambda function somehow. I'd probably look into sending the location of each of your existing S3 objects to a Kenesis stream and configure a Lambda function to pull records from that stream and process them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using s3cmd.

```
s3cmd modify --recursive --add-header="touched:touched" s3://path/to/s3/bucket-or-folder
```

This will modify metadata and invoke an event for lambda

Comment: Will this change the 'Last modified' timestamp of the s3 object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy your bucket content and catch create events with lambda.

copy:

```
s3cmd sync s3://from/this/bucket/ s3://to/this/bucket
```

for larger buckets:

https://github.com/paultuckey/s3_bucket_to_bucket_copy_py

Comment: Note that this approach will reset all of the dates on the objects to "now" and will incur charges for new object creation, since copying an object, even to the same key in the same bucket, technically creates a new object.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

1. Create another S3 Bucket
2. Create a lambda that will be triggered by this new S3 Bucket
3. Sync old bucket with new bucket.
4. Delete old bucket.

This is what I did but my bucket was not that huge.